# Solidity Error: TypeError: contract.detectNetwork is not a function

Tags: solidity, truffle, contract-deployment, javascript

When trying to run 'truffle migrate --reset' everything works and it seems that the contract deploys, however I get the error 'TypeError: contract.detectNetwork is not a function'. I have no idea what this means.

Any help is much appreciated.

**This is what the terminal is outputting:**

```
truffle migrate --reset

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\contracts\Migrations.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\pSDAToken.sol
> Artifacts written to C:\Users\xxx\first-smart-contracts\build\contracts
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.8.11+commit.d7f03943.Emscripten.clang


Starting migrations...
======================
> Network name:    'development'
> Network id:      5777
> Block gas limit: 6721975 (0x6691b7)


1_initial_migration.js
======================

   Replacing 'Migrations'
   ----------------------
   > transaction hash:    0xbd60a04b43bb50b42feda5cc78dceb57fea390d3a5699bb5d397d5cfa291eb25
   > Blocks: 0            Seconds: 0
   > contract address:    0x481A323B9A655A42042fE3aF133e3B41417c2877
   > block number:        46
   > block timestamp:     1645643067
   > account:             0xa250b2effe6C5FdFe248f843F02B076CF526bd9e
   > balance:             99.81572798
   > gas used:            248842 (0x3cc0a)
   > gas price:           20 gwei
   > value sent:          0 ETH
   > total cost:          0.00497684 ETH

   > Saving migration to chain.
   > Saving artifacts
   -------------------------------------
   > Total cost:          0.00497684 ETH


2_deploy_contracts.js
=====================

   Deploying 'pSDA'
   ----------------
   > transaction hash:    0xc750304aa9c61d7265be8b1890580b66930d1cf4c1bdfba1193bbcd09667216a
   > Blocks: 0            Seconds: 0
   > contract address:    0x3Cc33A9D9a59bFf75EC0909256D9571EC5E3F2F0
   > block number:        48
   > block timestamp:     1645643070
   > account:             0xa250b2effe6C5FdFe248f843F02B076CF526bd9e
   > balance:             99.79736654
   > gas used:            875559 (0xd5c27)
   > gas price:           20 gwei
   > value sent:          0 ETH
   > total cost:          0.01751118 ETH


Exiting: Review successful transactions manually by checking the transaction hashes above on Etherscan.


TypeError: contract.detectNetwork is not a function
    at Deployer._preFlightCheck (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\deployer\src\deployment.js:189:1)
    at C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\deployer\src\deployment.js:294:1
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
Truffle v5.5.1 (core: 5.5.1)
Node v16.13.2
```

**1_initial_migration.js:**

```
const Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

**2_deploy_contracts.js** :

```
var pSDAToken = artifacts.require("pSDA");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(pSDAToken, 60000000).then(function () {
        var tokenPrice = 1000000000000000;
        return deployer.deploy(pSDAToken.address, tokenPrice);
    });
};
```

**Here is my 'truffle-config.js' if that is any help:**

```
module.exports = {
networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1", 
      port: 7545,      
      network_id: "*",  
    },
  
compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.8.11",
    }
  }
};
```